# How to display posts from specific category in Ionic App Page

Tags: wordpress, cordova, ionic-framework, wp-api

I want to display all posts from a specific category e.g **Works** with id **1** in my wordpress site to the WorksPage in my Ionic app.

Below is the code that displays all the recent post on the main page/Home screen.
**HOMEPAGE/ALL --  home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PostPage } from '../post/post';
import { NavController, LoadingController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WordpressService } from '../../services/wordpress.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  posts: Array<any> = new Array<any>();
  morePagesAvailable: boolean = true;
  loggedUser: boolean = false;

  categoryId: number;
  categoryTitle: string;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public wordpressService: WordpressService,
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.authenticationService.getUser()
    .then(
      data => this.loggedUser = true,
      error => this.loggedUser = false
    );
    this.morePagesAvailable = true;

    //if we are browsing a category
    this.categoryId = this.navParams.get('id');
    this.categoryTitle = this.navParams.get('title');

    if(!(this.posts.length > 0)){
      let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
      loading.present();

      this.wordpressService.getRecentPosts(this.categoryId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        for(let post of data){
          post.excerpt.rendered = post.excerpt.rendered.split('<a')[0] + "</p>";
          this.posts.push(post);
        }
        loading.dismiss();
      });
    }
  }

  postTapped(event, post) {
    this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, {
      item: post
    });
  }

  doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }


  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    let page = (Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10)) + 1;
    let loading = true;

    this.wordpressService.getRecentPosts(this.categoryId, page)
    .subscribe(data => {
      for(let post of data){
        if(!loading){
          infiniteScroll.complete();
        }
        post.excerpt.rendered = post.excerpt.rendered.split('<a')[0] + "</p>";
        this.posts.push(post);
        loading = false;
      }
    }, err => {
      this.morePagesAvailable = false;
    })
  }

  /*logOut(){
    this.authenticationService.logOut()
    .then(
      res => this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage),
      err => console.log('Error in log out')
    )
  }

  goToLogin(){
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
  }*/
}
```

**home.html**

```
     <ion-list *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="postTapped($event, post)" class="cardList">
    <ion-card-content class="innerContent"> 
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="entityParams">
           <ion-col class="img" col-2><img id="roundpic" src="{{post.images.medium}}" class="thumbs" />
           </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-10 class="ParamsInner">
              <ion-row class="entity">{{post.custom_fields.entity}} </ion-row>
              <ion-row class="method"><ion-icon name="clipboard"></ion-icon> {{post.custom_fields.method}}</ion-row>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row class="ptb">
          <span [innerHTML]="post.title.rendered" class="postTitle"></span>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row class="cardbottom">
          <ion-col col-8 class="ref_number dotted-spaced-ref"> <ion-icon name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon> {{post.custom_fields.ref_number}} </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-4 class="deadline dotted-spaced-dline"><ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon> Ending:<br />{{post.custom_fields.deadline}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-list>
```

**Config file.ts**

```
//config constants
export const WORDPRESS_URL = 'http://www.example.com/wp/';
export const WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL = WORDPRESS_URL + 'wp-json/wp/v2/';
```

I have tried placing the code below in my **works.ts** file but instead it displays all recent posts and not posts of specific category(works)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PostPage } from '../post/post';
import { IonicPage, NavController, LoadingController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WordpressService } from '../../services/wordpress.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';

/**
 * Generated class for the WorksPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-works',
  templateUrl: 'works.html',
})
export class WorksPage {

  posts: Array<any> = new Array<any>();
  morePagesAvailable: boolean = true;
  loggedUser: boolean = false;

  categoryId: number;
  categoryTitle: string;

 constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public wordpressService: WordpressService,
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad WorksPage');
    //if we are browsing a category
    this.categoryId = this.navParams.get(1);
    this.categoryTitle = this.navParams.get('title');

    if(!(this.posts.length > 0)){
      let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
      loading.present();

      this.wordpressService.getRecentPosts(this.categoryId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        for(let post of data){
          post.excerpt.rendered = post.excerpt.rendered.split('<a')[0] + "</p>";
          this.posts.push(post);
        }
        loading.dismiss();
      });
    }
  }


  postTapped(event, post) {
    this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, {
      item: post
    });
  }

  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    let page = (Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10)) + 1;
    let loading = true;

    this.wordpressService.getRecentPosts(this.categoryId, page)
    .subscribe(data => {
      for(let post of data){
        if(!loading){
          infiniteScroll.complete();
        }
        post.excerpt.rendered = post.excerpt.rendered.split('<a')[0] + "</p>";
        this.posts.push(post);
        loading = false;
      }
    }, err => {
      this.morePagesAvailable = false;
    })
  }

}
```

***Added Edit***
there is this code being used in **services.ts** file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import * as Config from '../config';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

@Injectable()
export class WordpressService {
  constructor(public http: Http){}

  getRecentPosts(categoryId:number, page:number = 1){
    //if we want to query posts by category
    let category_url = categoryId? ("&categories=" + categoryId): "";

    return this.http.get(
      Config.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL
      + 'posts?page=' + page
      + category_url)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getComments(postId:number, page:number = 1){
    return this.http.get(
      Config.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL
      + "comments?post=" + postId
      + '&page=' + page)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getAuthor(author){
    return this.http.get(Config.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL + "users/" + author)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getPostCategories(post){
    let observableBatch = [];

    post.categories.forEach(category => {
      observableBatch.push(this.getCategory(category));
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
  }

  getCategory(category){
    return this.http.get(Config.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL + "categories/" + category)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  createComment(postId, user, comment){
    let header: Headers = new Headers();
    header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user.token);

    return this.http.post(Config.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL + "comments?token=" + user.token, {
      author_name: user.displayname,
      author_email: user.email,
      post: postId,
      content: comment
    },{ headers: header })
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look to the [WordPress rest api documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts) it says that you can send a `categories` parameter with the request:

so the url will be something like this:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/w2/posts?categories=1
```

That should only return all posts in that category if the Works category has the term_id 1

Comment: please check some additional code I have added. from the **services.ts** file

Comment: well after looking at the new code, can you debug so you get the category id to `getRecentPosts` function?
Or if you can post an url where your WordPress installation so I can test the Api calls

Comment: I decide to change this code `//if we are browsing a category
    this.categoryId = this.navParams.get('id');`  where i replace `this.navParams.get('id'); ` with `this.categoryId = 2;` **2** is the id of the category